# problem to reduce screen brightness

Tags: screen, brightness

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 and I'm having trouble turning down the screen brightness.  The brightness is always at maximum.  I've tried the brightness settings and the keyboard (fn) but the brightness doesn't change at all.  My PC has Core i7, 16GB RAM and Intel® Iris® Xe Graphics.  I've already updated Ubuntu to version 22.04 and I don't understand my problem.